# User is not authorized to perform rds:DescribeDBEnginerVersions Error RDS Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

When I navigate to RDS and try to create a new DB Instance, This error is displayed. Can anyone help as **What might be the cause?** How to solve this error? is this on my side or should I contact **AWS Help Centre?**

[image: Error Screenshot]

**TIA**

Comment: You have no permissions to access RDS. Are you an admin user? Who set IAM permissions for you?

Comment: I am  not an admin user. The client owns this account. I requested him for the persmissions. He stated that there are no such RDS kind of permissions available to be allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is such a permission. You can add it to your IAM user (or your admin can do it) in a number of ways. One way is through an [inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "rds:DescribeDBEngineVersions",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `"Resource": "*"` must be as is. `rds:DescribeDBEngineVersions` is a generic permission, not applicable to a specific database.

Answer (score 0):

In some case while creating a new database instance, you may be stack with **"Error loading resource You are not authorized to perform this operation. "** Even though you add all rds:* permission.

Apparently you need also EC2 permission, so the solution is :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeVpcAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "rds:Describe*",
                "rds:ListTagsForResource",
                "rds:CreateDBInstance",
                "rds:CreateDBSubnetGroup",
                "rds:DeleteDBInstance",
                "rds:StopDBInstance",
                "rds:StartDBInstance"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```